# What is the shortcut of "enable scrolling" in Acrobat X Pro?

Tags: shortcuts, adobe-acrobat

I like the button "Fit to window width and enable scrolling" very much, now I know the shortcut of fit to window width is Ctrl+2. So, how about enable scrolling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly long way is the chain: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

I am not aware of any built in shortcut. There is also the toolbar button: [image: Screenshot of toolbar button(s)]

---

If you get something like [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), you can set any hotkey you like:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class AcrobatSDIWindow
!S::SendInput {Alt}vpc
```

That's an AHK script to make <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> enable scrolling. `!S` means it activates on the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> hotkey. The `#IfWinActive` means it only activates if Acrobat or Reader (they use the same class) is focused. See more possible hotkeys [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

Just copy that to a text file and change the extension to `.ahk`. When you install AHK, it should set itself as the default program for that extension so just open the file to run it.

You can [set an AHK script to run on startup](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#Startup).

Comment: This is really a long solution...Then do you know a build in shortcut for "Fit to window width and enable scrolling," just the same as the button you captured?

Comment: @Elderry Unfortunately, I don't know of any. Another equally long winded (and probably worse) method is to use `Shift`+`F8` to focus on the toolbar and `Tab` or `Shift`+`Tab` however many times to move to that button - this is less reliable because the toolbars can change. The AHK solution, once set up, is quite easy - probably the easiest available.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the shortcut of “enable scrolling” in Acrobat X Pro?

Fast and easy way: press Ctrl+shift+H (Twice)

It will enable scrolling.

Comment: Why does this work?

Answer (score 3):

Edit » Preferences » Accessibility » Always use Page Layout Style. Check Single Page Continuous.

This helped me much more than having to keep switching it.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly my preferred settings most of the time,

I have a solution for you; albeit,
I could not find a way to create a shortcut, but I did indeed find a bypass "so to speak" to this issue, where you can change the default settings.

In Adobe Acrobat go to preferences (Ctrl + K) > page display > under default layout and zoom > change to single page continuous and fit width > click Ok

that's that

P.S
screenshot attached for reference

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxLVx.png]